# Automapper one source to multiple destination

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

Below is my class

```
class Dest1    
{    
 string prop1;
 string prop2;
 strig prop3;
 public Dest2 Dest2 {get;set;}
 pubic List<Dest3> Dest3 {get;set;}
}

class Dest2    
{   
 string prop4;
 string prop5;
 strig prop6;   
}

class Dest3        
{    
 string prop7;    
}

class Source1

{
 string prop1;
 string prop2;
 string prop3;
 string prop4;
 }
     class Source2
      {
 string prop7;
       }
```

I need to map

Q1. source1 class to Dest1 Class( also i need to map dest2 object)

Edit:

Q2. I need to do map Dest1 back to Source 1 (reverse map)

Am using .net core and auto mapper.. am new to automapper & .net core ..Thanks in advance

Comment: I have an interest in this question just because I have no idea what is being asked. It may be that there's something to learn here.

Comment: i have Source class  and i need to map this class to 2 sepearte class Dest1 and Dest 2 in automapper

Comment: You can create another Class that contains Dest1 and Dest2 as properties, or you can create a Map Profile for each one (Dest1 and Dest2) and then call Map method twice.

Comment: thanks ,,,am new automapper.. how to create mapping profile.can you some  psudo code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoMapper can map from as many sources to as many destinations as you would like, assuming you configure the mapping. For example, your requested scenario:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    // Mapping Config
    cfg.CreateMap<Source1, Dest2>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.prop5, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.prop6, opt => opt.Ignore());
    cfg.CreateMap<Source1, Dest1>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Dest2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

    // Reverse Mapping Config
    cfg.CreateMap<Dest1, Source1>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.prop4,
                   opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (src?.Dest2 != null) // ?. w/c#6 
                                             ? src.Dest2.prop4 // map if can
                                             : null)); // otherwise null
);
// Check AutoMapper configuration
configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Properties with the same name will map automatically. Any destination properties that don’t have a corresponding source property will need to be ignored.

Once your AutoMapper is configured, you can map as needed with the use of the IMapper interface.

```
public class Foo {
    private IMapper _mapper;
    public Foo(IMapper mapper) {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    // Map Source1 -> Dest1
    public Dest1 Bar(Source1 source) {
        return _mapper.Map<Dest1>(source);
    }

    // Map Dest1 -> Source1
    public Source1 Baz(Dest1 dest) {
        return _mapper.Map<Source1>(dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer..i just edited my qtn ..actually  public Dest2 Dest2 {get;set;} property exist in Dest1 class...can we auto mapper configuration in seperate class?

Comment: So you want to map prop1, prop2, and prop3 into the corresponding properties in Dest1 and prop4 into the corresponding property of Dest1’s Dest2 property?

Comment: yes..exacly..can u pls suggest i edited the question..thanks

Comment: Updated my answer to fit your new ask.

Comment: thanks a lot ..one last query .ForMember(dest => dest.prop5, opt => opt.Ignore()) is it necesary...?

Comment: Yes. If destination members don’t have a source member to map from, the mapper will throw an exception if you don’t tell it to ignore. This only applies for destination members though. If source members don’t have somewhere to map to, they will be automatically ignored.

Comment: Thanks.. if  public Dest2 Dest2 {get;set;} is list then i am getting error...for list is there any chnages,,,

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. Can you update your question with your new code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Q2, but I can answer Q3. Can you clarify Q2? I'm guessing you want to map Dest1 back into Source1 based on how you worded it, but it is unclear. Also, I'm not sure what the SO etiquette is, but I think since this is more than one question now, you are supposed to mark this one solved and post additional questions as separate questions. If you do, just link them here, and I'll go answer those.

Comment: i edited Q2 ..pls anser and  created another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653642/automapper-mapping-objects

Comment: Updated answer per Q2. Please note that ?. notation requires c#6. If you can't use that, you basically just need to validate the property before mapping so you don't end up with a null ref exception.

Comment: Also answered Q3 that you created on the other page. Thanks for doing that. I didn't want any mods flagging the question for multiple questions/questions inconsistent with the title.