# automapper mapping objects

Tags: c#, automapper

This additional requirement based on this question [one source to mutiple destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63643577/automapper-one-source-to-multiple-destination)

```
class Dest1    
{    
 string prop1;
 string prop2;
 string prop3;
 pubic List<Dest3> Dests3 {get;set;}
}

    class Dest3        
    {    
     string prop7;    
   string prop8;
    }

 class Source2
 {
 string prop7;
 string prop8;
 }
```

1. i need to map Source2 to Dest1  in auto mapper ( Dest3 is a list also need to  mapped)

My mappping class:(not working)

```
 CreateMap<Source2, Dest3>();
            CreateMap<Source2, Dest1>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Dests3 , opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, assuming that when this mapping occurs Dests3 should be a single item list, the configuration for this should look something like this:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
// Mapping Config
cfg.CreateMap<Source2, Dest1>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.prop1, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.prop2, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.prop3, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Dests3, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => 
                                                      new List<Dest3> { 
                                                          new Dest3 {
                                                              prop7 = src.prop7,
                                                              prop8 = src.prop8
                                                          }
                                                      }));

// Check AutoMapper configuration
configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Then, you can use the mapper to handle the mapping wherever you need, like so:

```
public class Foo {
    private IMapper _mapper;
    public Foo(IMapper mapper) {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    // Map Source2 -> Dest1
    public Dest1 Bar(Source2 source) {
        return _mapper.Map<Dest1>(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...is it possible  replace somthing firstordefault in this case  because i have 15+ properties  similar https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html

Comment: You can't use FirstOrDefault in this case. You're mapping from a string to a list of objects with a string property. In other words, the list is null before you map. FirstOrDefault would only be an option if you were mapping from the list to the string.

Comment: thanks..if source2 has other properties can use like this rite?  new List<Dest3> { 
                                                          new Dest3 {
                                                              prop7 = src, prop8=src;
                                                          }

Comment: Yes/no. Your comment made me realize I missed a part in my configuration. Updated the answer to fix that/answer your question.